# Issue with linebreaks inside tables when dealing with .docx documents

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx

The following code takes the path of an .docx document, goes through it and prints the content of every cell in all tables.

```
public void parse(String path) throws IOException {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path);
    XWPFDocument ex = new XWPFDocument(fis);
    XWPFWordExtractor extractor = new XWPFWordExtractor(ex);
    List<IBodyElement> docIter = ex.getBodyElements();
    Iterator<IBodyElement> iter = docIter.iterator();
    for (IBdyElement iBodyElement2 : docIter) {
        if (iBodyElement2 instanceof XWPFTable) {
            XWPFTable table = (XWPFTable) iBodyElement2;
                for (int i = 0; i < table.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
                    XWPFTableRow row = table.getRow(i);
                        List<XWPFTableCell> rowcells = row.getTableCells();
                        for (XWPFTableCell xwpfTableCell : rowcells) {
                            System.out.print(xwpfTableCell.getText());
                    }
            }
        }
    }
```

When I run this code on a .docx document with a table in it will print strings from a cell without linebreaks.
For example, if a cell is filled with the string "Foo
Bar" it will be printed as "FooBar". This is a huge problem for me.

Is there a way to read the cells that preserves the linebreak?

Comment: Rather than calling `getText()` (which glues all the contents together), did you try fetching the individual runs in the cell and printing those out one by one?

Comment: Do you mean like row.getCell(1).getText()? In that case, it does not help (also, I have no idea how to get the number of columns/cells in a table, so would be hard to iterate over)

Comment: No. From a given `XWPFTableCell`, you'll want to fetch the `XWPFRun` instances

Comment: Hm, sorry for the silly question, but how do I get the assosicated xwpfrun. I can't find any reference to this in XWPFTableCell's API.

Comment: You'll need to go via Paragraphs or (nested) Tables - see [the javadocs](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFTableCell.html) for details of how to get those two, which both contain runs